# Asymptotic for binomial sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Let $S(n, t) = \sum_{k = 0}^n  {n \choose k} ^t$.

The task is to find asymptotic behavior of $S(n,5)$, $n \to \infty$.

Asymptotic for $S(n,0)$ and $S(n,1)$ is very simple.

For $S(n,2)$ we can use convolution for generating functions.

But, for case $n = 5$ I need help.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A005261

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the answer in the paper [Mark C. Wilson, Diagonal asymptotics for products of combinatorial classes](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~mcw/Research/Outputs/Wils2013.pdf): $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^d\sim\sqrt{\frac{2^{d-1}}{d}}\frac{2^{dn}}{(\pi
n)^{\frac{d-1}{2} }}$$